# sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) Cannot operate on a closed database

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlalchemy

I simplified my code so it can be reproduced. The "select empty template file" popup can be any file. I did contact the author of uszipcode and he is super nice and told me that the way I'm using tkinter is causing the problem and that I should put my core logic inside the def of button to avoid it. However, I wish to only use tkinter to obtain file names. Even though there is an exception message, I still get all the results I want.

(My full code is about minimizing shipping distance: say I have fileone contain 10000 orders with order detail and zipcodes, filetwo contain the location of 100 warehouses and their zipcodes, and filethree contain the formatting template for warehouses. I used tkinter to obtain these three filenames, write the data in dataframes, and then calculate the nearest zipcode distance from 100000 orders to the 100 warehouses and choose the closest warehouse, and convert the order details to the formatting that warehouses need.) I would be very grateful for your inputs or feedbacks!

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

def browse_button3():
    global folder_path3
    filenameq3 = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    folder_path3.set(filenameq3)
    print(filenameq3)

root = tk.Tk()
folder_path3 = StringVar()
lbl1 = Label(master=root,textvariable=folder_path3)
lbl1.grid(row=1, column=3)
button3 = Button(text="\n        Select Empty Template File      \n        Select Empty Template File      \n        Select Empty Template File      \n", command=browse_button3,bg='green', fg='black',)
button3.grid(row=1, column=3)
root.mainloop()
    

from uszipcode import SearchEngine
engine = SearchEngine()


zipp=engine.by_zipcode('46067')
coords_1 = (zipp.lat, zipp.lng)

print(coords_1)



Exception ignored in: <function SearchEngine.__del__ at 0x000002B520053040>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uszipcode\search.py", line 196, in __del__
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uszipcode\search.py", line 202, in close
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1757, in close
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1799, in _close_impl
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 923, in close
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2287, in close
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2503, in _do_close
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2489, in _close_impl
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2481, in _connection_rollback_impl
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 960, in _rollback_impl
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1995, in _handle_dbapi_exception
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 958, in _rollback_impl
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 667, in do_rollback
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) Cannot operate on a closed database.
```

Comment: Is this just a repeat of an earlier question? Please don't ask the same question twice.

Comment: Yes. I deleted the earlier question because the code was not reproducible and it seems I cannot edit that question.

Comment: And after replying to your comment...I just found the "edit" button below the question...o(╥﹏╥)o

Comment: Call `engine.close()` at the end.  I wonder why having this issue after using tkinter!  There is no issue when just executing the code behind `mainloop()`.

Comment: It is found that the error is nothing related to tkinter.  The issue can be reproduced by just adding a dummy function definition, e.g. `def abc(): pass`, even without those tkinter code.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering about the same thing. The author did send me some comment, which I did not fully understand. But I think he means that by having the "def button" part (GUI), the uszipcode will run with the GUI, when GUI is closed, it will try to access a closed database (even though I haven't call the engine yet). And I'm very new to python, so I did not quite understand what is happening.